# Showing calendar Control

Tags: c#

I am creating a web application in which i have to select a date. I am using Calendar control. But it occupies too much space and other labels and text boxes are not shown in proper alignment. Is there anything I Can do in which when i click on an image, the calendar control opens, but on the textbox, so that it does not occupy any space.

Regards,
Jigar

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use a purely client side date picker, which displays a "pop-in" calendar when the `TextBox` is selected. Search the web for ["date picker"](http://www.google.dk/search?q=date+picker) to find tons of JavaScript implementations, including the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker).

Comment: +1 client side calendars are the way to go. I prefer the extjs one myself.